# Continuous collision detection

Tags: xna, collision-detection, game-engine

Quite a simple question, with continuous collision detection do I need to check both entities if they're both moving or just the fastest one of the two? I was thinking only the fastest of the two need checking but I'm not so sure if that's right. Any clarification would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Check both, then check only one, see if there is any difference and then choose either one of them. Are you having some sort of problem with your CD, or is it just "which one is better" kind of questions?

Comment: @user1306322 No it's more just trying to avoid unnecessary checks. I've currently got continious collision detection on one set of entities (projectiles) and I'm just trying to work out if it needs to be implemented on the other set as well(aircraft). So when you say check both and see if there is any differece, any difference in what?

Comment: If it works fine right now, I suggest you leave it be and develop the rest of your project. They call it "premature optimization". Just make sure everything else that uses this approach can safely switch to a new one in future, if you ever decide to change it.

Comment: @user1306322 Well it works fine for anything that's moving, I've come across a situation where I have a static entity e.g. a mine, where I now instead need the aircraft to perform the raycasting instead. I suppose I was wondering with this behaviour needing to be performed for the mine, whether I'd actually need to perform it for eevrything else anyway.

Comment: I can only give general advice on that — try every reasonable combination and choose one of the working ones. Later on, if you feel the game slows down significantly because of this unoptimized method, you can get back to it, but right now I suggest you focus on other important things.